# Roku In-Channel subscription Method

Tags: roku, brightscript

For roku billing system  when we searched we found out we can create susbriction method as per month or per year or for certain period of time method but we want to know is it possible to make 1 time payment subscription ? And Can anyone explain in detail for thr in channel subscription  method?